# How to create distinct groups in LP?

Tags: linear-programming, minimax

Say you have the following table:

|  | Season Crop Price |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spring | Cauliflower | 175g |
| Spring | Coffee | 15g |
| Summer | Blueberry | 50g |
| Fall | Beet | 100g |
| Fall | Eggplant | 60g |

I want to choose the best selling crop for each season, or what gives the maximal price.

How do I write a model that captures this?

I know that my maximal function must be something like :

```
decision variable
x = crop

list = price_of_crop

maximize(x[i] *list[i])
```

But how to get the distinction for each section?

Feel free to add more to this if it helps make it clearer, I am not an OR expert.

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. You have not articulated any constraints, other than apparently wanting a single crop for each season. So what stops you from just looking at the table and picking the best selling crop in each season (no modeling required)?